# Call enableLatestRenderer cause flicker children in <Marker />

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps

After a recommendation from Google Maps Platfrom I decide to update to the latest renderer for the Maps SDK for Android. Following react-native-maps documentation I call enableLatestRenderer() in App.js. The issue that I was facing was that all markers started flickering.

If I use tracksViewChanges={false} flickering stops but this is not a solution for me since I use Animate.Image to scale selected marker. The scaling stops working if tracksViewChange is false

This is my custom marker

```
  return (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      coordinate={{
        latitude: Number(marker.lat),
        longitude: Number(marker.lng),
      }}
      // tracksViewChanges={false}
      onPress={(e) => onMarkerPress(e)}>
      <Animated.View style={styles.markerStyle}>
        <Animated.Image
          source={require('../../assets/images/appicon.webp')}
          resizeMode='contain'
          style={[styles.markerImage, scaleStyle]}></Animated.Image>
      </Animated.View>
    </Marker>
  );
```

Comment: Does the flickering happen also using the `LEGACY` renderer?

Comment: From what I can see from trying this out, though I can't reproduce the flickering issue, the `<Marker />` component of the `react-native-maps` seems to be utilizing the new [Advanced Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/advanced-markers/add-marker) instead of the Legacy one. So you might want to check it out if your implementation steps should change also.

Comment: The flickering happens only if enableLatestRenderer() is called in App.js. If it is removed works fine. The problem is only on Android devices. On iOS device works fine because I use Apple maps.

Comment: On the Android platform calling enableLatestRenderer() returns Promise and the result is LATEST

Comment: Saw a recent issue posted on the github repo of `react-native-maps`, have you seen this before? https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4988 Some provided workarounds that you might what to try out.